# Azure Table get more 1000 items

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have some code for select data from Azure Tables:

```
 IQueryable<DataEntity> data =
                    (from e in table.CreateQuery<DataEntity>()
                     where
                         String.Compare(e.PartitionKey,
                             string.Format("{0:0000000000000000000}", start),
                             StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0 &&
                         String.Compare(e.PartitionKey, string.Format("{0:0000000000000000000}", end),
                             StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0
                     select e);
                data.AsTableQuery().Execute();
```

Is work good, but return just 1000 items and I don't know how to return more items.
I found this code:

```
  do
            {
                TableQuerySegment<DataEntity> tableQueryResult =
                    await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(tableQuery, continuationToken);

                continuationToken = tableQueryResult.ContinuationToken;

                allCount += tableQueryResult.Results.Count;

            } while (continuationToken != null);
```

But I don't know how to remake my code with use **ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync**.
And how to get **ContinuationToken**?
Help me please with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Address");
        TableContinuationToken token = null;
        IQueryable<DynamicTableEntity> data = (
            from e in table.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()
            select e
            );
        long entitiesCount = 0;
        do
        {
            var result = data.AsTableQuery().ExecuteSegmented(token);
            token = result.ContinuationToken;
            var entities = result.Results;
            entitiesCount += entities.Count;
            Console.WriteLine(entitiesCount + " entities fetched");
        } while (token != null );
```

Essentially you will need to call [`ExecuteSegmented`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn451537.aspx) method instead of `Execute`.